# jQuery css multiple Transform attributes wont work

Tags: jquery, css, transformation

can anyone explain me how to get multiple Transform attributes work in jQuery.css() ?

i have set up a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ervg4qbd/4/) to show what I mean

This wont work:

```
$('.transformMe').css({
    'border':'5px dotted blue',
    '-webkit-transform': 'scale(5) translate(60,25)',
    '-moz-transform': 'scale(5) translate(60,25)',
    '-ms-transform': 'scale(5) translate(60,25)',
    '-o-transform': 'scale(5) translate(60,25)',
    'transform': 'scale(5) translate(60,25)'
});
```

This results in a new border but the transformation is ignored by the browser.

This Works:

```
$('.transformMe2').css({
    'border':'5px double green',
    '-webkit-transform': 'scale(5)',
    '-moz-transform': 'scale(5)',
    '-ms-transform': 'scale(5)',
    '-o-transform': 'scale(5)',
    'transform': 'scale(5)'
});
```

How can I set multiple transform attributes with jQuery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `PX` in `translate(60px,25px)`

```
$('.transformMe').css({
    'border':'5px dotted blue',
    '-webkit-transform': 'scale(5) translate(60px,25px)',
    '-moz-transform': 'scale(5) translate(60px,25px)',
    '-ms-transform': 'scale(5) translate(60px,25px)',
    '-o-transform': 'scale(5) translate(60px,25px)',
    'transform': 'scale(5) translate(60px,25px)'
});
```

**DEMO  USING A BETTER APPROCH AND JQUERY**

```js
$('.transformMe').addClass("dottedBlue");

$('.transformMe2').addClass("dottedGreen");
```

```css
.transformMe{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
    left:150px;
}
.transformMe2{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
    left:450px;
}

.dottedBlue{
    border:5px dotted blue;
    -webkit-transform: scale(5) translate(60px,25px);
    -moz-transform: scale(5) translate(60px,25px);
    -ms-transform: scale(5) translate(60px,25px);
    -o-transform: scale(5) translate(60px,25px);
    transform: scale(5) translate(60px,25px)
}
.dottedGreen{
    border: 5px double green;
    -webkit-transform: scale(5);
    -moz-transform: scale(5);
    -ms-transform: scale(5);
    -o-transform: scale(5);
    transform: scale(5)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="transformMe"></div>
<div class="transformMe2"></div>
```